# Term for an item that is both selected and visible

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I have an HTML table of items. Items can be hidden, filtered or selected, so I am currently using the terms "selected", "visible", "filtered" and "all" to indicate which items the user wants to include in the data output.

What I need is a good term for items that are both "selected" and "visible" to the user. I have thought about using "chosen" or "result". Maybe there is a better term?

---

Update:

- selected = items selected using a checkbox
- visible = items that are currently visible. Some items may be hidden due to pagination.
- filtered = items that remain after being filtered out by user query.
- all = all items. It doesn't matter if the item is hidden, filtered out or unselected.

Currently there is no selection for items that are both selected and hidden, which is possible if items are paginated.

Comment: Please explain what each of the terms you are using means **in context**, operationally. Otherwise, this question risks being closed as unclear. To help you, people shouldn't need to guess the behavior/situation.

Comment: Can an item ever be "invisible" **and** "selected"? If not, there appears to be no need to distinguish "selected" items from items that are both "selected" **and** "visible".

Comment: Please see my updated question; if you need an actual example, click on the down arrow next to the download button in [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html) - the "selected" option is not yet available. @ElleFie Yes, items can be "invisible" and "selected" if pagination has been applied.

Comment: It is possible for items to be selected and (truly) invisible?  Isn't there a difference between hidden and not in view because of pagination/scrolling?  You could say "this page" instead of visible.

Comment: Not all developers may choose to use pagination, so "this page" may be confusing to the user.

Comment: *Highlighted* perhaps?

Comment: This may sound strange... but somehow I feel *checked out* is best fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling a selected and visible object "active" but this term skews more toward the "selected" side of the equation.

Comment: I ended up just calling it "selected+visible", not very clever but at least everyone knows what it means.